# Prove that polynomial $1+x+x^2$ of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$. Do not use the Eisenstein criterion.

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Prove that $1+x+x^2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Do not use the Eisenstein criterion.

I don’t know where to start. Could someone help me?

Comment: If it is reducible, it separates into linear factors. In other words, it has a root in $\mathbb R$. But, the discriminant $1-4=-3<0$, so there are no roots in $\mathbb R$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: You probably know how to factor it in $\mathbb C[x]$ (use quadratic formula).  But irreducible factors there are unique, and neither factor belongs to subring $\mathbb R[x]$, so the polynomial is irreducible in the subring.  Your remark not to "use the Eisenstein criterion" suggest the context for this problem is beyond early undergraduate studies, but you've omitted such context.  Please edit to include such.

Comment: Also note that the Eisenstein criterion can never be applied on polynomials over a field.

Answer (score 8):

For all $x\in\mathbb R$, $x^2+x+1=\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34>0$, so $x^2+x+1$ has no roots in $\mathbb R$.

A quadratic polynomial with no roots is irreducible.

Comment: So when a polynomial has no roots, it is considered unreducible?

Comment: When a *quadratic* (or cubic) polynomial has no roots, it is irreducible, [but not generally](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222237/irreducible-polynomial-means-no-roots)

Comment: How could I give a counterexample in this case?

Comment: A counterexample to what?

Comment: Not to be irreducible in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $(x-1)(x-2)=x^2-3x+2\;$ is reducible over $\Bbb R$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117859/discussion-between-fernando-sousa-and-j-w-tanner).